Unable to connect with AgentDVR in ubuntu machine via localhost:8090
I have installed AgentDVR in my linux system using the below script :
bash <(curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ispysoftware/agent-install-scripts/main/v2/install.sh")
It got installed in my device successfully without any error as below:
vijay@vijay-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~$ bash <(curl -s "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ispysoftware/agent-install-scripts/main/v2/install.sh")

Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.0.0 InRelease [1,572 B]

Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.0.0 InRelease [1,572 B]

Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease

Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease

Hit:4 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease

Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease

Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]

Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]

Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease

Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease

Fetched 229 kB in 2s (95.3 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Done

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

alsa-utils is already the newest version (1.2.6-1ubuntu1).

fontconfig is already the newest version (2.13.1-4.2ubuntu5).

libxext-dev is already the newest version (2:1.3.4-1build1).

unzip is already the newest version (6.0-26ubuntu3.2).

apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.4.12).

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

libcudnn9-samples

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Finding installer for x86_64

Downloading https://ispyfiles.azureedge.net/downloads/Agent_Linux64_5_3_5_0.zip

% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current

Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed

100 59.7M 100 59.7M 0 0 308k 0 0:03:18 0:03:18 --:--:-- 339k

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

unzip is already the newest version (6.0-26ubuntu3.2).

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

libcudnn9-samples

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

Archive: AgentDVR.zip

inflating: Agent

extracting: agent-register.sh

extracting: agent-reset-account.sh

extracting: agent-reset-local-login.sh

extracting: agent-reset.sh

inflating: agent-uninstall-service.sh

inflating: agent-update.sh

inflating: Agent.dll.config

creating: Content/

creating: Content/Commands/

extracting: Content/Commands/Alerts Off.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Alerts On.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/All Off.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/All On.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Apply Schedule.bat

inflating: Content/Commands/readme.txt

extracting: Content/Commands/Record Off.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Record on Alert.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Record on Detect.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Restart Agent.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Run Storage Mgmt.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Snapshot.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Start Record.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Stop Cloud Uploads.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Stop Record.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/Stop Streaming.bat

extracting: Content/Commands/_Example.bat

creating: Content/Masks/

inflating: Content/Masks/demo_mask.png

creating: Content/sounds/

inflating: Content/sounds/airhorn.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/alarm.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/alsationxsiberian_bark.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/alsation_bark.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/cairnterrierbark.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/doorbell.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/police.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/pop.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/rottweiler_bark.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/spanielgrowlbark.wav

inflating: Content/sounds/wiggle.wav

inflating: CoreLogic.dll.config

inflating: libcvextern.so

inflating: libe_sqlite3.so

inflating: libjingle_peerconnection_so.so

inflating: libndi.so

inflating: libonnxruntime.so

inflating: libSDL2.so

inflating: libSkiaSharp.so

inflating: libSystem.IO.Ports.Native.so

inflating: setup-ffmpeg-linux.sh

creating: XML/

inflating: XML/config.xml

creating: XML/haarcascades/

inflating: XML/haarcascades/catface.xml

inflating: XML/haarcascades/face.xml

inflating: XML/layouts.xml

inflating: XML/objects.xml

inflating: XML/PTZ2.xml

inflating: XML/Sources.xml

inflating: XML/Translations.xml

Downloading start script for back compat

% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current

Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed

100 97 100 97 0 0 267 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 267

Adding execute permissions

Adding permission for local device access

The user \vijay' is already a member of `video'.`

To run Agent either call ./Agent from the terminal or install it as a system service.

Setup AgentDVR as system service (y/n)? y

Yes

Installing service as vijay

% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current

Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed

100 489 100 489 0 0 830 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 828

Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/AgentDVR.service.

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/AgentDVR.service → /etc/systemd/system/AgentDVR.service.

Started service

Go to http://localhost:8090 to configure


So Now In the provided URL localhost:8090 , I often receive Connection Lost error.( For every minute ). I am unable to add new Device . If I try so , The page goes blank and tells site cannot be reached error.
Somehow, I have connected with a Network camera using this agentDVR which is working fine in VLC. Even When I try to remove that device I am unable to do that because of the connection fails error.
I don't konw why this is happening and how to fix ?
I have already installed the AgentDVR and worked without this problem. For some reasons I have installed new OS and installed the AgentDVR again as I mentioned above. Now I face this error which I havenot faced on y first time.
I have also tried some fixes as below :

Stopping and restarting it using below commands:

sudo systemctl stop AgentDVR.service 
sudo systemctl start AgentDVR.service

Try reinstalling AgentDVR again.

None of the aboeve methods fixed my issue.
